# uint8 vs uin256 constant variable

Tags: solidity, tokens, gas, dapp-development

Why do people use uint8 for constant variables such as decimals for tokens, isn't it better to use uint256? the EVM would need to use additional calls to go from 256/32bits to 8 and therefore increase gas costs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With optimization enabled, there will be no extra gas cost for using `uint8` constants instead of `uint256` constants. The conversion instructions are optimized away entirely.

With optimization disabled, there is a small extra gas cost.

I just tested it, and with optimization disabled the use of a `uint8` constant gave 3 bytes of bytecode more than the use of a `uint256` constant.

With optimization enabled, the Solidity compiler gives the exact same bytecode in both cases.

Comment: why is it important to specify uint type anymore then? one could just go with uint right

Comment: @NemesisChain Off-chain code may rely on a value fitting in 32 or 64 bits. Smaller uint's can be used in your API to eliminate edge-cases involving overflow and truncation, thereby simplifying code.